# How to get value from the inside of for loop in javascript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise

I need help in Typescript ( javascript ), waiting for the code inside the for loop to be done first

I have input ( textbox ) to get string from the user and search in it for #Number ( #50 ) I had done a function to read start index of '#' and I need to get the numbers only after the # so I had used the for loop to compare each character with SPACE to read the number value but I believe that return value it returns before the for loop finish how can I make the return wait for the FOR loop to be done and update the internal variable before it returns the value back  ...

```
  readNumber(text: string): number {
    const start = text.indexOf('#') + 1;
    let newText = '';
    for (let index = start; index < text.length; index++) {
      if (text.slice(index, 1) === ' ') {
        newText = text.slice(start, index - start);
      }
    }
    return +newText;
  }
```

if the user will enter this value " employee #56 cv" I need to get this output 56

Comment: *"but I believe that return value it returns before the for loop finish"* What makes you believe that?

Comment: Side note: `text.slice(index, 1)` can be simply `text[index]` on any vaguely modern browser (and also IE8+).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loop will continue after your assignment to `newText`, yes. If you want to stop it at that point, use `break`:

```
newText = text.slice(start, index - start);
break;
```

But you can also avoid the loop entirely by using `indexOf` again:

```
readNumber(text: string): number {
  const start = text.indexOf('#') + 1;
  if (start === -1) {
      return 0; // Or whatever you should return when there's no # character
  }
  const end = text.indexOf(' ', start);
  if (end === -1) {
      end = text.length;
  }
  return +text.substring(start, end);
}
```

Or a regular expression:

```
readNumber(text: string): number {
  const match = /[^#]*#(\d+)/.exec(text);
  if (!match) {
      return 0; // Or whatever you should return when there's no # character
  }
  return +match[1];
}
```

That's *slightly* different from your example in that it doesn't look for a space, it just looks for a run of digits. To use a space instead:

```
readNumber(text: string): number {
  const match = /[^#]*#([^ ]*)(?: |$)/.exec(text);
  if (!match) {
      return 0; // Or whatever you should return when there's no # character
  }
  return +match[1];
}
```